# Get variable from function at included fil

Tags: php, web

I'm trying to use variables from a `function` which is in an external file. To achieve this, I'm using the include `function` to include that file (functions.php) into my primary file (insert.php) and trying to `echo` variable from `functions.php`.

My primary file is **insert.php** which includes the following:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <?php
           include 'functions.php';
           external_functin();
           echo $primary_var0."<br />";
           echo $secondary_var0;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**functions.php** file:

```
<?php          
    function external_function(){
       include 'mysql_connection.php';
       $query="SELECT * FROM db_table";
       $exec=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
       $i=0;
       if(mysqli_num_rows($exec)>0){
            while($result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($exec)){#This while script stores the query result values to variables.
              ${"primary_var".$i} = $result['field_name'];
              ${"secondary_var".$i} = $result['id'];
              $i++;
            }   
         }
      }
 ?>
```

The issue is that everytime I load / run insert.php, since it has syntax to `echo` `$primary_var0` and `$secondary_var0`, I get an `undifined index error.`

Help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to return the values from the function, it's the same as if the function was on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables created inside function `external_function()` will not be available outside this function scope.

You have at least two ways to get them:

a) by reference

```
// functions.php
function external_function(&$primary, &$secondary) {
   //...
   $primary = $primary_var0;
   $secondary = $secondary_var0;
}

// insert.php
$primary_var0;
$secondary_var0;
external_function($primary_var0, $secondary_var0);
echo $primary_var0;
echo $secondary_var0;
```

b) by returned value

```
// functions.php
function external_function() {
   //...
   return [$primary_var0, $secondary_var0];
}

// insert.php
list($primary_var0, $secondary_var0) = external_function();
echo $primary_var0;
echo $secondary_var0;
```

c) by using `array` with variable names and values + [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function

```
// functions.php
function external_function(){
    // its just simulation of results from Database
    $resultsFromDB = [];
    $resultsFromDB[] = ['id' => 1, 'field_name' => 'something'];
    $resultsFromDB[] = ['id' => 2, 'field_name' => 'other'];
    $resultsFromDB[] = ['id' => 3, 'field_name' => 'value'];

    $i = 0;
    $variables = [];
    foreach($resultsFromDB as $result) {
        $variables["primary_var".$i] = $result['field_name'];
        $variables["secondary_var".$i] = $result['id'];
        $i++;
    }   

    return $variables;
}

// insert.php
$variables = external_function();
extract($variables);

echo $primary_var0 . ' ' . $primary_var1 . ' ' . $primary_var2 . '<br>';
// something other value

echo $secondary_var0 . ' ' . $secondary_var1 . ' ' . $secondary_var2;
// 1 2 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your ideas @Mateusz. As you can see, in my while loop in functions.php, I am assigning dynamic variables: ${"primary_var".$i} and  ${"secondary_var".$i}. Is it in anyway possible to return dynamic variables at the end of the function ?

Comment: Yes, there are another ways to do that, I edited answer and added the third option c), take a look ;)

Answer (score 1):

you should return data for your function `external_function` to work .
   so you can try this

```
 <?php          
    function external_function(){
                include 'mysql_connection.php';
                $query="SELECT * FROM db_table";
                $exec=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                $i=0;
                if(mysqli_num_rows($exec)>0){
                    while($result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($exec)){#This while script stores the query result values to variables.
                    $data['primary_var'][$i] = $result['field_name'];
                    $data['secondary_var'][$i] = $result['id'];
                    $i++;
                    }
                  return $data ;
                }

        }
?>
```

and you can access your data in the view like this

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <?php
    include 'functions.php';
    external_functin();
    echo $data['primary_var'][0]."<br />";
    echo $data['secondary_var'][0];
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `external_function()` defined in functions.php and return some value like so:

```
function external_function(){
    return 'some value';
}
```

then when you call `external_function()` in insert.php like so:

```
echo external_function();
```

It will echo out: "some value"

if you want to return multiple values you can return an array like so:

```
return array('key1'=>'val1', 'key2'=>'val2');
```